# Passing 2D arrays (matrix) to functions in Arduino for Neural Networks

Tags: arrays, function, matrix, arduino, neural-network

I know there are another post talking about this, but I feel they don't help me, I want to do functions to multiply matrix and sum matrix, and one for print too. I need this to work with neural networks

```
/*
Function to matrix multiplication:

All the matrix need to be declarated

 r1 = row of the first matrix
 c1 = column of the first matrix
 r2 = row of the first matrix
 c2 = column of the first matrix

 first = A matrix
 second = B matrix
 mult = C matrix, or A * B
*/
void dot(int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2, float first[][c1], float second[][c2], float mult[][c2])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < c1; ++k)
            {
                mult[i][j] += first[i][k] * second[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should work with declarated matrix, it works in C, but I need this in Arduino

What can i do?

This is for sum:

```
/*
Function to sum matrixs:

All the matrix need to be declarated and equal in rows and columns

 r = row of the matrix
 c = column of the matrix

 first = A matrix
 second = B matrix
 sum = C matrix, or A + B
*/
void sum(int r, int c, float first[][c], int second[][c], float sum[][c])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        {
            sum[i][j] = first[i][j] + second[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

This is for print, but isn't important:

```
/*
Function to print matrixs:

 r = row of the matrix
 c = column of the matrix

 first = A matrix
 second = B matrix
 sum = C matrix, or A + B
*/
void printMatrix(int r, int c, float matrix[r][c])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        Serial.print('[ ');
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            Serial.print(' ');
            Serial.print(matrix[i][j]);
            Serial.print(' ');
        }
        Serial.print(']');
        Serial.println("\n");
    }
}
```

I really need help

Comment: Arduino is known for little RAM and not throwing Exceptions. "Neural networks" smell like more than 2kB RAM. If this does not apply, what's your exact problem?

Comment: Hi, the code does not compile, the structure of the function is correct for C, but not for arduino

Comment: `declaration of 'matrix' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first` . So `void printMatrix(int r, int c, float matrix[][3]) {...}` would work. That's a c++ problem, not Arduino.